# PHP, search and delete files from directory - performance

Tags: php, performance, file, search

I want to delete cache files in a directory, the directory can contain up to 50.000 files. I currently I use this function.

```
// Deletes all files in $type directory that start with $start

    function clearCache($type,$start)
        {
        $open = opendir($GLOBALS['DOC_ROOT']."/cache/".$type."/");
        while( ($file = readdir($open)) !== false ) 
            {
            if ( strpos($file, $start)!==false ) 
                {
                unlink($GLOBALS['DOC_ROOT']."/cache/".$type."/".$file);
                }
            }
        closedir($open);        
        }
```

This works fine and it is fast, but is there any faster way to do this? (scan_dir seems to be slow). I can move the cache to memory obviously.

Thanks,
hamlet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look into the [glob](http://php.net/glob) function, as it may be even faster... it depends on the C library's glob command to do its work.

I haven't tested this, but I think this would work::

```
foreach (glob($GLOBALS['DOC_ROOT']."/cache/".$type."/".$start) as $file) {
    unlink($GLOBALS['DOC_ROOT']."/cache/".$type."/".$file);
}
```

Edit: I'm not sure if $file would be just the filename or the entire path.  glob's documentation implies just the filename.

Comment: Looks good, first tests show that this is at least twice as fast. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't use your solution but the `glob` function has led me to another solution using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Either `glob` as suggested before or, if you can be certain there won't be malicious input, by issueing directly to the system via `exec(sprintf('rm %s/sess*', realpath($path)));`, which should be fastest.